# PHP Check if a date range happens during another date range

Tags: php, datetime, time, comparison

What I need to do is check a "task" does not occur during a lunch hour. I have 4 datetime objects. The closest code I have found is below but does not cover all possible scenarios, for example the start of the task could be halfway through lunch.

```
 if (($thisStart <= $lunchStart) && ($thisEnd >= $lunchStart)) {
     //happen at same time
 }
```

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($thisStart >= $lunchStart && $thisStart <= $lunchEnd)
{
    //occurs during lunch
 } else if ($thisEnd >= $lunchStart && $thisEnd <= $lunchEnd)
{
    //occurs during lunch
}
```

That should work for you.

However can you clarify what you mean by it doesn't cover all the times?

Comment: My code will also check whether or not a task starts before the lunch, but ends during it!

Answer (score 1):

Here you need this logic
Change time to second so it will be easy

but your date should be in ("y/m/d") format

```
$thisStart_1 = strtotime($thisStart);


$lunchStart_1 = strtotime($lunchStart);  


$thisEnd_1 = strtotime($thisEnd);
```

your Time will look like that for example:-
2014-04-30------->1398808800 (in second)

**So here you you get your time on second so it will be easy to check the time managment..**

```
if (($thisStart_1 <= $lunchStart_1) && ($thisEnd_1 >= $lunchStart_1)) {
     //happen at same time
 }
```

IF YOUR DATE IN DIFFERENT FORMAT THEN USE THIS:-

date in your format-*/

```
$gDate='30/04/2014';//whatever format here put same in this "date_create_from_format" function
```

change date format for make it usable by strtotime function

```
 $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $gDate);
```

echo forate to check the really format

```
$askfrmt = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

strtotime function on your given date

```
$askfrmta = strtotime($askfrmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure to have understanded your question, but if you want to know if `thisStart` and `thisEnd` are both during lunch try this:

```
if (!($thisStart > $lunchEnd || $thisEnd < $lunchStart) ){    
// Occurs during lunch
}
```